# Clear/ Reset Resource Provider

Tags: sql, resources, globalization

How do you get access to the Resource Provider for the current context?

I have a web page that allows a client to edit their Globalization values which are stored in SQL.

However pages still utilize the cached values until the app domain is freed.

How can I force clear/reset the provider and or get access to it to clear its cache.

Thanks,

Andy

Comment: if you have the answer could you put it here? i'm looking for the same answer.

Comment: Not exactly what I want to be doing.  But this gets the job done of resetting the cache... and app.

HttpRuntime.UnloadAppDomain();

Comment: That would effect all other users. In the worst case even those who are in the middle of a request. I'm using a custom resource provider now.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but i ran into the same issue and couldnt find the answer. in the end i mage a call to getobject with a predefined key which would clear the cached resources for that category

```
object IResourceProvider.GetObject(string resourceKey, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (resourceKey == GlobalConstants.RefreshResourceCacheKey)
        {
            _resourceCache = new ListDictionary();
            return null;
        }
```

Maybe not the best solution but the only one i could find